# How to update mod_wsgi to latest version on Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: 10.04, package-management, updates

My Ubuntu server has this version installed:

```
# dpkg -l | grep wsgi
ii  libapache2-mod-wsgi  2.8-2ubuntu1  Python WSGI adapter module for Apache
```

How can I get the [latest Version 3.3](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/downloads/list)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download and compile it. There is a pretty good *README* in their source package. But you can start by installing `build-essential` the basic system for compiling, then just follow the *README*

Comment: Make sure to disable mod_wsgi before you install the newer version 3.3. My Apache crashed with error `seg fault or similar nasty error detected in the parent process`.

Answer (score 1):

sudo apt-get build-dep libapache2-mod-wsgi

And then you can build from source reading the readme

Answer (score 1):

Debian has [libapache2-mod-wsgi](http://packages.debian.org/unstable/python/libapache2-mod-wsgi), but this won't work on Ubuntu 10.04 because it depends on libpython2.7 for which there's no package for 10.04.

I downloaded the source from [here](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/downloads/list):

```
$ wget http://modwsgi.googlecode.com/files/mod_wsgi-3.3.tar.gz
```

Then just

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was running this :

```
sudo aptitude install libapache2-mod-wsgi
```

Comment: Pranav, please be more specific. You need to explain the things so that people can get a clear idea about your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had mod_wsgi installed for python 2.7. I ran the below command to uninstall 2.7 and install 3.6 (my python version).

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi
```