# Ubuntu 10.04 updating mod_wsgi to version 3.4: still shows 2.8

Tags: apache2, django

I've followed instructions on

- [How to update mod_wsgi to latest version on Ubuntu 10.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2254/how-to-update-mod-wsgi-to-latest-version-on-ubuntu-10-04)

  and
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/installing-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-12-04

After an apache restart and a `dpkg -l | grep wsgi` I still see:

`ii libapache2-mod-wsgi 2.8-2ubuntu1`

Looking in `/usr/lib/apache2/modules` the mod_wsgi.so was modified today, so I assume it is the correct version but can't say for sure (is there a way to check?).

My `mods-available/mod_wsgi.load` shows the path to the recently modified `/usr/lib/apache2/modues/mod_wsgi.so`

Am I missing configuring something else, be it apache or otherwise, that would cause this module not to be updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloaded mod_wsgi3.3:
`$ sudo wget http://modwsgi.googlecode.com/files/mod_wsgi-3.3.tar.gz`

Removing the old version using `$ sudo apt-get purge libapache2-mod-wsgi` followed by a rebuild and finally adding `LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so` to *httpd.conf* solved my problem.